# Get Specific User Role's aspnet users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm using membership provider and i wanted to get some users in some user role.In my scenario this is "Supervisors"

But in here i'm having a trouble to get a list of UserRole's user list ( Supervisors).

[image]

My View

```
  @Html.DropDownList("drpsup", ViewBag.SupervisorList as System.Web.Mvc.SelectList, "-- Select Supervisor--", new { @class = "form-control", id = "drpdsuplst" })
```

My Model

```
public class Supervisors
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
public ActionResult InterviewerManagement()
    {
        UserBusiness _ub = new UserBusiness();
        var sRole =_ub.GetSupervisors();
        ViewBag.SupervisorList = new SelectList(supList, "UserId", "UserName", 0);
```

My Business Class

```
    public IList<Supervisors> GetSupervisors()
    {
        var AllUsr = iuserrepository.GetList(x => x.UserId != null);
        var xRole = irolerepository.GetSingle(x => x.RoleName.Equals("Supervisor"));
        var yRole = iusersinrolerepository.GetList(x => x.RoleId.Equals(xRole.RoleId));

       // var supRole = iuserrepository.GetList(x => x.UserId != null).Select(x=>x.UserId.Equals(yRole.Where(d=>d.)).ToList();


        return supRole;
    }


        return View();
    }
```

In my business class i just comment var supRole.... i know littlefix to it solve the problem.But o have no idea to do it.

Comment: Can you show us your `User` and `Role` entities?

Comment: @ChrFin It's normal Membership provider tables and in the Business class xRole & yRole list comes successfully.